# Code first approach to create database with column type object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

This is my class which has a property Value of type "object"

```
public class Answers : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public object[] KeyValues
    {
        get { return new object[] { this.Id }; }
    }

}
```

so when the entity framework creates a table in database, It creates columns for all the properties except **Value**.

There is no column created at all for Value property. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What database column type were you expecting?

Comment: @hvd can I get a column of type object?

Comment: If your database has a data type "object", it's not any database I know. :)

Comment: @hvd  So how do I achieve it. I need to store the Value into database
Value can be (string,integer,picture,sound file,audio file) etc :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your database entities you can only have the types which can be mapped to column types of your DB table.

To have something like array of objects you should create viewmodel and then map that viewmodel with your DB entities.

Comment: I have a UI to create random questions, And expected answer is of type "Object" (any datatype should be supported eg.pic.jpg,string,etc). So is it possible to create a column in DB that supports insertion of Object?

Comment: If i understand your requirement correctly, You can store that in form of byte array in db so in your DB model class you can have a property of type byte[] and in your poco or viewmodel you can have object type which can be mapped to this

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Let me try this one. :)

Comment: Sure, it should work. By the way you can write your own code to convert object type into byte[] or you can use third party dll like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: Thank you @HBhatia. This would be the solution for my question.